# Convert the content of sobject into the list of Id

Tags: apex, soql

I have an invoice Object which is connected to contact through case.

I have a list of invoices which contain list of contactIds.

This is what I have done:

```
List <Invoice__c> lstInv = [select Breach__r.Contact.Id from Invoice__c where Id=: objInv.Id];
```

I want the values in this list to added in below list:

```
List <Id> lstId = new List <Id>;
```

Update:

I have written the below code but it returns null in lstId.

```
trigger sendInvoicePDF on Invoice__c (After Insert) {
 List <Id> lstId = new List <Id>();
  for (Invoice__c objInv: trigger.new) {

    lstId.add(objInv.Breach__r.ContactId);

   system.debug('@@@@' + lstId);
   SendVF_Email.sendEmail(lstId);
 }
}
```

Comment: You want to populate list `lstId` with contact ids?

Comment: We dont have stream /lambda as of now so you have to use for loops

Comment: I have used the below code but it is returning 0 results in the lstId:                              trigger sendInvoicePDF on Invoice__c (After Insert) {
 List <Id> lstId = new List <Id>();
  for (Invoice__c objInv: trigger.new) {
  
    lstId.add(objInv.Breach__r.ContactId);
  
   system.debug('@@@@' + lstId);
   SendVF_Email.sendEmail(lstId);
 }
}

Comment: That is not the same as the code you posted above. You have to perform a query to get those related values.

Answer (score 2):

There's no shorthand way in which this could be done, you need to traverse the query results and use the iterator for adding the Contact IDs to the list.
Psuedo code -

```
for (every invoice say "inv" in query results) {
    add inv.Breach__r.Contact.Id in lstId
}
```

Additionally, I will suggest you to add a check for Breach__r and Contact not null. Also the name "lstId" is ambiguous, rename it to something list "lstContactId" to maintain clarity.